# How to get number from string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, split

i have a string like `String[] str = {"[5, 2, 3]","[2, 2, 3, 10, 6]"}` and i need to take numbers to add into an integer list.

i tried to split first index into numbers to see if it will work, looks like:

```
String[] par = str[0].split("[, ?.@]+");
```

After the split i tried to see what array i get:

```
for(String a: par)
    System.out.println(a);
```

But when i wrote that code i get an array like this:

```
[5
2
3]
```

So, how can i get rid of this square brackets?

Comment: You know exactly which strings have which brackets, and you know exactly where they will be.  What is preventing you from removing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your current pattern, I would use `\\D+` which will split on one or more non-digits. Add a guard for the empty string too. Something like

```
String[] str = { "[5, 2, 3]", "[2, 2, 3, 10, 6]" };
for (String par : str) {
    for (String t : par.split("\\D+")) {
        if (t.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(t));
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
5
2
3
2
2
3
10
6
```